# How to I pass an array from my Controller to the Model and then send it back?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to set up an array in the controller which the model grabs in setArray, then I reverse the order and use getArray to return it so that the controller can tell the view to print it out.

#### Controller

```
public class ReverseArrayController extends Controller {

    protected ReverseArray myModel;
    public ReverseArrayController( View theView, ReverseArray theModel){
        super(theView);
        myModel = theModel;
    }
    public void go() {


        myView.start();
        myModel.setArray int([12, 56, 34, 79, 26]);
        myModel.reverse();
        myView.say ("The Array Reversed is " + myModel.getArray());

        try {
            myView.stop();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

#### My Model

```
public class ReverseArray { 

    private int myArray[];

    public void setArray(int[] theArray){
        myArray = theArray;         
    }

    public void reverse(int[] myArray){ 
        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length / 2; i++) {
            int temp = myArray[i]; // swap numbers 
            myArray[i] = myArray[myArray.length - 1 - i]; 
            myArray[myArray.length - 1 - i] = temp; }   
    }

    public int[] getArray(){
        return myArray;                     
    }   
}
```

Comment: Don't understand your question, your code has done what you wanted except  the syntax error of this: `myModel.setArray int([12, 56, 34, 79, 26]);`

Comment: Mikey, what's wrong with your current code? How is it not behaving as expected? Can you please improve this question by supplying any and all pertinent context?

Comment: I'm not even sure if I'm setting the array properly in the controller subclass. Getting syntax error on tokens. I think the Model is ok but not too sure. Also not sure if the reverse array is written out properly in the controller... or the get array for that matter.